# Cannot resolve AppCompatActivity after upgrade project from gradle 2.1 to 3.5

Tags: android

I successfully upgrade gradle from 2.10 to 3.5 to build APK in android studio 3, but have problem like this
[image: Cannot Resolve AppCompatActiviy]

And this is my build gradle [image: Build Gradle]

Comment: use latest v7 version instead of 23.4.0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity - Support v7 libraries aren't recognized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803405/cannot-resolve-symbol-appcompatactivity-support-v7-libraries-arent-recognized)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29199891/cannot-resolve-symbol-appcompatactivity

Comment: Have you tried support lib version `26.1.0` or `27.0.2`?

Comment: @ZaidMirza your comment is right, because I use library 25 for build tools I update v7 to 25.x.x and it works, need you to answer this so I can accept your answer.

Comment: @NileshRathod in that question the answer is android studio is weird thing? is not the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to update `gradle` version specially `3.1+` than you might need to upgrade `support lib` version too. its weird but it seems compatibility issues between `gradle` version and `support lib` version.

Comment: and please restart android studio if the issue still appeared