# What is .idea folder in Android Studio 3.2.12?

Tags: android-studio

I meet the problem *Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity*

I solved the problem by deleting  .idea folder and syncing project with gradle files by the acticle [Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity - Support v7 libraries aren't recognized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803405/cannot-resolve-symbol-appcompatactivity-support-v7-libraries-arent-recognized)

Could tell me what .idea folder is ? Why can I delete it and sync ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

.idea folder is storing the settings for your IDE (Development Environment) - so the settings of Android Studio how to visualize your project.
You can check more about .idea folder [here](https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207097529-What-is-the-idea-folder-)

Answer (score 6):

The **.idea folder** (hidden on OS X) in the solution root contains IntelliJ's project specific settings files. These include per-project details such as VCS mapping and run and debug configurations, as well as per-user details, such as currently open files, navigation history and currently selected configuration.

Some files should be committed to source control, some should be excluded.

See here: https://rider-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207097529-What-is-the-idea-folder-

Answer (score 4):

It stores project specific IDE settings that pertain to AndroidStudio. It is called `.idea` because AndroidStudio is derived from JetBrains' Intellij IDEA. Most if not all IDEs in the Intellij family create such a directory. Examples include Rider, an IDE specialized for writing code targeting the .NET Framework, and JetBrains Intellij itself, an IDE specialized for writing code targeting the JVM.

Basically it is for project scoped IDE configuration.