# How to add dependencies?

Tags: android, gradle

I am using Android studio version 4.0

In Project level gradle :

```
def supportVersion = "27.1.0"
ext.deps = [
    supportAppCompat   : "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion",
    supportDesign      : "com.android.support:design:$supportVersion",
 
]
```

Module level gradle :

```
dependencies {    
implementation deps.supportAppCompat
implementation deps.supportDesign
}
```

When I import this it occurs an error

[image: error pic]

when I import this

```
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
```

Error in xml

[error pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhDwM.png)

when add this tags in xml an error occurs

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout/>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout/>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton />
```

give a solution for this!!!

Answer (score 1):

As Of Google Official Document (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages)

***Note: With the release of Support Library 28.0.0, the android.support-packaged libraries are deprecated and replaced by individually-versioned Jetpack libraries packaged as androidx. The initial 1.0.0 release of the Jetpack libraries provides parity with Support Library 28.0.0 and provides a starting point for migrating to the new androidx packaging.***

To fix the error:

```
"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVersion"
"com.android.support:design:$supportVersion"
```

to

```
def supportVersion = "1.0.0"
ext.deps = [
    supportAppCompat   : "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$supportVersion",
    supportDesign      : "com.google.android.material:material:$supportVersion",
]
```

After that either restart Android Studio or Refresh is cache data as-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIjWP.png)

More information on this this thread: [Cannot resolve symbol AppCompatActivity - Support v7 libraries aren't recognized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30803405/cannot-resolve-symbol-appcompatactivity-support-v7-libraries-arent-recognized)

**For forcing android studio to use old library**

I check you are using 27.1.0, so we can force android studio not to use androidx

- Go to gradle.properties
- make these flags false

  android.useAndroidX=false

  android.enableJetifier=false

Comment: @Poorvaja if you are using androidx library, make sure you use the following - androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout , make sure to refresh the android studio cache

Answer (score 0):

as you using android studio **4.0**

use androidX library instead of Support Library...as latest version uses androidx

```
    dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: add dependencies in build.gradle which i gave in my answer and then sync now..then accordingly import in class and xml

Comment: use this xml tags `androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout`  instead of  `<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout/>`    use and import androidx tags

Answer (score 0):

You can migrate your **supportAppCompat** to the AndroidX library.

In the menu go to Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX. Then you should reimport androidx in your classes.